Why does fat get stuck to ice after solidification?
Suppose we put ice cubes into soup, which consists of saturated fat in liquid form and water in liquid form. When we put ice cube inside of it, fat gets solidified and when we remove ice cube, fat is stuck around the ice.
My question is: Why the fat is stuck to the ice? Why doesn't it just stay into the soup into the solid form?

Temperature gradient. The fat near the ice cubes cools and solidifies. No magic involved.Wait an hour or two, and the fat will be back in the soup again, if the allover temperature is still above the melting point of the fat.
The soup away from the ice cubes is still warm enough to keep those fats liquid. And, because the solid form is not liquid, it will not travel away from where it is attached to.

well, i know temperature gradient is doing its thing, but when i take out ice, solidified fat gets stuck to ice. it doesnt stay into the soup.

You say: "solidified fat gets stuck to ice. it doesnt stay into the soup. " ... that's because it's solidified. Without any external force, it sticks to whatever solid it is already attached to. In your case, these are the ice cubes. Wait until the ice cubes are melted, and the fat (if not melted, too, by that time) will be back in the soup again. Mind you, this procedure will separate different kinds of fat (with different melting points) and the soup will not be tasty any more.

Can you expain it into more details? i want to grasp the concept of it being stuck to whatever solid it is already attached to. i need that part to be explained. also to clarify something. we actually after several seconds pull the ice out of the soup

You asked: "Can you expain it into more details?" and I have to say, no, not in detail. There are many reasons why solid matter sticks together (it would not be solid matter but separated particles, then). Hope https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force will give you helping information.
